# "ld returned 1 exit status" in simple program

Tags: multiplication

can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?
Im trying to pass the value of 'amount' and 'count' into int main where it displays the multiplication. I get the error "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status" with the int main() highlighted. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void show(int, int);
int display()
{
    int amount;
    int count;
    amount = 10;
    count = 20;

    return(0);
}

int main(int amount, int count)
{
    show(amount, count);
    int sum;
    sum = amount * count;

    printf("%d", sum);


    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You should pass command line parameters to the main using the `argv[]` instead of trying to define your own parameters

Comment: can you give me and example please? ive never used argv[] before

Answer (score 0):

The error's cause is that your main function's signature is rejected by ld, which is expected because the standard signatures for main are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.

If you want to pass amount and count as parameters to main, that is as command-line parameters, you should use the second signature I gave for main, where argv is an array of the command line parameters and argc gives the number of elements in argv. Note that argv[0] is not a command line parameter but the name under which your program was called and that argv[argc] is a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass command line parameters to the main using `argc` and `*argv[]` instead of trying to define your own.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This prints the paramters passed to `main()` via the command line.

If you pass a value for amount a and a value for count via the command line, you can access them like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "amount" << argv[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count" << argv[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Used index 1 and 2 of `argv` because index 0 contains the program name

You specified no language so I used C++ for the above example, but the idea is the same for C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("amount %s", argv[1]);
    printf("count %s", argv[2]);
}
```

Note that the incoming values are char arrays, not integers